# Does Laravel Query Builder Save the Query Without Assignment?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code

```
$user = User::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('status', 'active');


if ($request->get('get_devs') {
    $user->where('occupation', 'developer');
} else if ($request->get('sys_admins')) {
    $user->where('occupation', 'sys_admins');
}

// get either devs or sys_admins
$result = $user->get()->toArray();
```

Will Laravel Query builder preserve the previous 'User::where' query and save the next queries even if I do not do any assigning? Is that behaviour the same for Query Builder and for Collections?

Answer (score 1):

> Will Laravel Query builder preserve the previous 'User::where' query
>   and save the next queries even if I do not do any assigning?

Yes, since you're working with query builder object and it stores your query in it's properties you don't lose anything unless you create a new instance...

> Is that behaviour the same for Query Builder and for Collections?

Not for collection since collection passes a new instance every time you use a method of it. for example take a look at `merge` method of collection it returns

`return new static(array_values($dictionary))`

so every time you get a new instance of collection and because of that it's different than query builder...

A little tip, you can improve your code by using `when` method it's like `if` statement but much more easier and convenient

```php
$user = User::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('status', 'active')->when($request->get('get_devs'), function ($query) {
            $query->where('occupation', 'developer');
        })->when($request->get('sys_admins'), function ($query) {
            $query->where('occupation', 'sys_admins');
        })->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

### No need for doing any assigning for Eloquent Builder or Query Builder

Because you are creating an **Eloquent Builder instance**.

And Eloquent Builder have a property named [query](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L31), its type is **Query-Builder**.

So when executing `where` on Eloquent-Builder, Eloquent-Builder will do `where` method on its property `$query`:

```php
    /**
     * Add a basic where clause to the query.
     *
     * @param  string|array|\Closure  $column
     * @param  mixed   $operator
     * @param  mixed   $value
     * @param  string  $boolean
     * @return $this
     */
    public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
    {
        if ($column instanceof Closure) {
            $column($query = $this->model->newModelQuery());

            $this->query->addNestedWhereQuery($query->getQuery(), $boolean);
        } else {
            $this->query->where(...func_get_args());
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

So execute `where` on Eloquent-Builder will be effect on its property, the instance of Query-Builder. It will change the Query-Builder instance's properties' value, like the [where](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L104) constraints for the query.

### Need assigning for Collection

Collection has a property named [items](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L49), which is an array.

When you using `where` on collection. Collection use filter-method:

```php
    public function where($key, $operator = null, $value = null)
    {
        return $this->filter($this->operatorForWhere(...func_get_args()));
    }
```

Filter-method will return a new value by `array_filter`:

```php
      return new static(array_filter($this->items));
```

The collection's property `$items` is not changed, so you need to assign to the variable if you want the result.

Comment: Actually `$items` change since it assigned in constructor.

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand I mean the value of property `$items` is not changed after using `where`